# What influence does a magnetic field have on a Bose-Einstein condensate?

Tags: magnetic-fields, quantum-entanglement, bose-einstein-condensate

Perhaps the answer could include the following possible scenarios:

- a static external magnetic field supports the formation of a BEC,
- the magnetic field maintains the BEC longer as the temperature rises,
- a changing magnetic field destroys the BEC,

or other aspects.

Comment: do you mean on the theoretical ideal process of BEC, or experimentally/realistically?

Comment: @SuperCiocia More interested in real observations. :-) But anyway, what do you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the magnetic fields are utilised. For example,

**Static external magnetic fields** can support a BEC as long as the field has a non-zero field minimum such as the [Ioffe Pritchard trap](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/epl/i1998-00107-2/meta) or the time-averaged orbiting potential trap [(TOP trap)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-4075/33/19/319/meta). Thermal atoms can be trapped in a quadrupole magnetic field, which has a field zero. However, when using radio-frequency cooling to remove the hottest atoms in a quadrupole field to lower the temperature towards BEC, atoms around the field zero undergo Majorana spin flips and are lost from the trap. The atoms that are lost are the coolest (low energy) atoms, this is then a heating mechanism which prohibits the creation of a BEC in the magnetic trap having a field zero.

**Changing magnetic fields** can also cause Majorana spin flips, if the rate of change of the field is comparable to the Lamor precession frequency then spin flips will occur, this is how forced rf evaporation works and is a method to cool and create BECs in magnetic traps, but can also be a loss and heating mechanism. Note that this also occurs for atoms moving within a static field as the field is moving from the atoms frame of reference, and is the loss mechanism discussed above.

**Combining static and time dependent magnetic fields** can be used to create radio-frequency dressed potentials. The static field defines a quantisation axis and splits the degeneracy of the magnetic sub levels, and the time dependent field couples the sub levels. Under the right conditions atoms are trapped in a surface of resonance and the polarisation of the time dependent fields used to modulate the potential within it. BECs have been [produced](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys125) in these traps. The advantage of these traps is that the potential landscape can be dynamically controlled with the phase of the time dependent fields, such that beams splitters and interferometers can be realised for BECs.

Comment: jamie1989 Thanks for the answer. If I understand correctly, the BEC can be trapped and cooled in this way. And what about assisting the alignment of the spin of the particles by a magnetic field to get entangled states between the particles? Is it possible to reach a higher temperature with a stronger magnetic field before the BEC dissolves?

Comment: To be added: splitting the degeneracy among $m_F$ levels is necessary in order to have all the atoms in a single (and strecthed) spin state, otherwise there would be spin-changing collisions which would lead to energy released and ejection from the trap. Also, magnetic fields change the scattering lengths of atoms (via a Feshbach resonance) and hence the interactions strength and sign (attractive or repulsive): one can increase interactions for better thermal contact in e.g. evaporation, but negative interactions cause the BEC to implode and collapse.